# Controlling rotation path in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

On my top down 2.5D shooter game, I am using`Quaternion.LookRotation()` and `Quaternion.Lerp()` to change the rotation of my player towards a click. 
 The player rotates just fine, but I need more control over the rotation path.
  The issue here is that the LookRotation() always returns the shortest path to complete the rotation. 
 I need the player to always rotate only in the X axis until its either +90 or -90 and then flip in the Y axis to the other side. 
It doesn't matter if the player rotate + or - 90 degrees over the X axis, but the idea is to always rotate in the X axis, before flipping from 1 frame to another, then rotating again in the X axis towards the click.

Here are some images illustrating the above. The "X" in red below, is where the "click" happened.

[image: The X marks where the click happened]
[image: The player turns on the x-axis only]
[image: When the x-axis is either = or - 90 degress the player flips on the y-axis]
[image: Finish rotating towards the click on the x-axis]

Comment: The lerp is just interpolating between the values - meaning the LookRotation is what is taking the shortest path of rotation. You will need to use a different type of rotation, split up over several steps like you've explained to achieve this. lerping the rotation using Quaternion.Euler() will probably come in handy.